# Htaccess forces php to run twice

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have following .htaccess, to format get info.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?csbuilder\.io [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem is when I apply this rule, it starts to run php script twice!
I figured that out, because one piece of code being processed twice.

That script sets random token in database, and any time I reload the page, in database I see different token, that is being sent to browser.

If I remove .htaccess rule, it works fine.

Any ideas?

---

**Solved:**

Existing rule matchs everything. If you will have broken image, it will match it, and run through *index.php*.

So we don't need to match images, and other files. So changing regex to following, solved the issue.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-/])+$ index.php?params=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Because if removing the `.htaccess` makes it *work fine*, I'm tempted to answer: just remove the `.htaccess`.

Comment: This rule by itself will not run `index.php` twice per one request. What may be happening is `index.php` outputs resource links (eg Javascript, CSS, images) that cause the browser to send another request to the server, which invokes `index.php`.

Comment: I had an image file, which does not exists, so it was running it through index.php. I will change .htaccess to check the request to not be an image. Thanks

Comment: or change `.+` to just `[\w-]+` so that image/css/js are not matched

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since everything is rewritten to go through `index.php`, a common pattern with a lot of routing engines, you may see multiple executions for *different paths*, so pay very close attention to your access log. The most common offender here is the browser asking for `/favicon.ico` without any prompting.

Comment: I had an image file, which does not exists, so it was running it through index.php. I will change .htaccess to check the request to not be an image. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you can ignore common image extensions with `\.(gif|png|jpe?g|ico)`.

Comment: One thing to consider is routing missing images to a missing image placeholder of some kind, or even a single pixel image. This avoids the common problem of accidentally serving HTML for a broken `<img>` tag.