# CSRF Token - two random tokens instead of one after refreshing

Tags: php, token, csrf

Could you please explain me why after refreshing generates two random tokens instead of one?

Part of my code:

```
function getToken() {
    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    if(!isset($_SESSION['tokens'])) {
        $_SESSION['tokens'] = array($token => true);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['tokens'][$token] = true;
    }
    return $token;
}

$token = getToken();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

After first open a page output is:

```
  'tokens' => 
    array (size=1)
      '3bf8398a3bcf0e99d114e6c683501d27427172bda9e79eec8c9b70fa5a5eb2eb' => boolean true
```

but after refresh 3 tokens instead of 2:

```
  'tokens' => 
    array (size=3)
      '3bf8398a3bcf0e99d114e6c683501d27427172bda9e79eec8c9b70fa5a5eb2eb' => boolean true
      'f83e53ea730a26aca4ea8de7c07dc58637144e910ccb672745d82c33db3fbb93' => boolean true
      '86c4dec388b0383d24a97340a03e85574db9f81c7d66360ebbbe42d0921e7aa4' => boolean true
```

and after next one +2 more and so on.

I try to find why it happens and fix it.

Comment: `$_SESSION['tokens'][$token] = true;` every time it hits that function, it creates a brand new `$token`, and assigns it. You probably want to only generate a token if one does not exist, otherwise grab the token from the session.

Comment: Because `$token` is different each time, it gets added to `$_SESSION['tokens']` as a new entry. Unless you specifically `unset()` the old ones after you no longer need them, they'll stick around as long as the session is active.

Comment: But why it adds two new tokens in session array instead of one more after call this function?

Answer (score 1):

Basically your function is saying this: if no token. create one. if one does exist, lets add another one.

You can try this instead. If no token exists, create one it. And return the session token variable.

```
function getToken() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    }
    
    return $_SESSION['token'];
}

$token = getToken();
```

Comment: I found where the problem was. This topic with similar problem like I had - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820582/htaccess-forces-php-to-run-twice